# Can gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT be used as the format of cubemaps?

Tags: webgl

In trying to create VSM shadows that work on mobile platforms I'm exploring the possibility of 24 bit depth textures to store the moments (some mobile platforms don't support floating-point textures).

The problem is that I need omni-lights with shadows which means I need cubemaps (ideally). At least firefox does not seem to support this, printing `Error: WebGL warning: texImage2D: With format DEPTH_COMPONENT24, this function may only be called with target=TEXTURE_2D, data=null, and level=0.` to the console.

I'm calling gl.texImage2D with DEPTH_COMPONENT as format and internal format. For type I've tried gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, gl.UNSIGNED_INT and ext.UNSIGNED_INT_24_8_WEBGL, all to no avail.

I could map the sides of a cube to a 2d texture and add a margin to each side to avoid interpolation artifacts but that seems overly involved and hard to maintain.

Are there other workarounds to have sampler cubes with DEPTH_COMPONENT format?

This is for WebGL 1

---

EDIT: I've made a few modifications to the code in gman's answer to better reflect my problem. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/h660x5my/)'s a jsfiddle. It looks like to does work on chrome (dark red cube on red background) but not on firefox (everything is black).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use depth textures you need to try to enable the [`WEBGL_depth_texture` extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_depth_texture/). note that [many mobile devices don't support depth textures](http://webglstats.com/webgl/extension/WEBGL_depth_texture). (click the filters in the top left)

Then, [according to the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_depth_texture/), you don't pass `DEPTH_COMPONENT24` to `texImage2D`. In pass `DEPTH_COMPONENT` and a type of `gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT` or `gl.UNSIGNED_INT` the implementation chooses the bit depth. You can check what resolution you got by calling `gl.getParameter(gl.DEPTH_BITS)`;

```js
function main() {
  const m4 = twgl.m4;
  const v3 = twgl.v3;
  const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
  const ext = gl.getExtension("WEBGL_depth_texture");
  if (!ext) {
    alert("Need WEBGL_depth_texture");
    return;
  }

  const width = 128;
  const height = 128;
  const depthTex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, depthTex);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height, 0, 
                gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, gl.UNSIGNED_INT, null);
  // calls gl.bindTexture, gl.texParameteri
  twgl.setTextureParameters(gl, depthTex, {
    minMag: gl.NEAREST,
    wrap: gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE,
  });

  // calls gl.createTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.texImage2D, gl.texParameteri
  const cubeTex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
    target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,
    minMag: gl.NEAREST,
    wrap: gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE,
    width: width,
    height: height,
  });
  const faces = [
    gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X,  
    gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X,
    gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y,
    gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y,
    gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z,
    gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z,
  ];
  const fbs = faces.map(face => {
    const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, face, cubeTex, 0);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.TEXTURE_2D, depthTex, 0);
    const status = gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (status !== gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
      console.log("can't use this framebuffer attachment combo");
    }
    return fb;
  });  

  const vs = `
  attribute vec4 position;
  attribute vec3 normal;
  uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;
  uniform mat4 u_worldInverseTranspose;
  varying vec3 v_normal;
  void main() {
    gl_Position = u_worldViewProjection * position;
    v_normal = (u_worldInverseTranspose * vec4(normal, 0)).xyz;
  }
  `;
  const fs = `
  precision mediump float; 
  uniform vec3 u_color;
  uniform vec3 u_lightDir;
  varying vec3 v_normal;
  void main() {
    float light = dot(u_lightDir, normalize(v_normal)) * .5 + .5;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(u_color * light, 1);
  }
  `;
  
  const vs2 = `
  attribute vec4 position;
  uniform mat4 u_matrix;
  varying vec3 v_texcoord;
  void main() {
    gl_Position = u_matrix * position;
    v_texcoord = position.xyz;
  }
  `;
  const fs2 = `
  precision mediump float; 
  uniform samplerCube u_cube;
  varying vec3 v_texcoord;
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = textureCube(u_cube, normalize(v_texcoord));
  }
  `;


  // compile shaders, links program, looks up locations
  const colorProgramInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
  // compile shaders, links program, looks up locations
  const cubeProgramInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs2, fs2]);
  // calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData
  const cubeBufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl);
  
  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;  // seconds
    
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    gl.useProgram(colorProgramInfo.program);
    // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
    twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, colorProgramInfo, cubeBufferInfo);

    // draw a different color on each face
    faces.forEach((face, ndx) => {
      const c = ndx + 1;
      const color = [
        (c & 0x1) ? 1 : 0,
        (c & 0x2) ? 1 : 0,
        (c & 0x4) ? 1 : 0,
      ];      
      gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fbs[ndx]);
      gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height);
      gl.clearColor(1 - color[0], 1 - color[1], 1 - color[2], 1);
      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

      const fov = Math.PI * 0.25;
      const aspect = width / height;
      const zNear = 0.001;
      const zFar = 100;
      const projection = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
      const world = m4.translation([0, 0, -3]);
      m4.rotateY(world, Math.PI * .1  * c * time, world);
      m4.rotateX(world, Math.PI * .15 * c * time, world);

      // calls gl.uniformXXX
      twgl.setUniforms(colorProgramInfo, {
         u_color: color,
         u_lightDir: v3.normalize([1, 5, 10]),
         u_worldViewProjection: m4.multiply(projection, world),
         u_worldInverseTranspose: m4.transpose(m4.inverse(world)),
      });

      // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
      twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, cubeBufferInfo);
    });

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.useProgram(cubeProgramInfo.program);
    // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
    twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, cubeProgramInfo, cubeBufferInfo);

    const fov = Math.PI * 0.25;
    const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
    const zNear = 0.001;
    const zFar = 10;
    const mat = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
    m4.translate(mat, [0, 0, -2], mat);
    m4.rotateY(mat, Math.PI * .25 * time, mat);
    m4.rotateX(mat, Math.PI * .25 * time, mat);

    twgl.setUniforms(cubeProgramInfo, {
      u_cube: cubeTex,
      u_matrix: mat,
    });

    // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
    twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, cubeBufferInfo);
    
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
main();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Otherwise you can use depth renderbuffers. [Where's an example](http://webglsamples.org/dynamic-cubemap/dynamic-cubemap.html) who's [code is here](https://github.com/WebGLSamples/WebGLSamples.github.io/blob/master/dynamic-cubemap/dynamic-cubemap.html) and the [code that creates the framebuffers for the cubemap is here](https://github.com/WebGLSamples/WebGLSamples.github.io/blob/master/tdl/framebuffers.js#L201).

---

### Update

As for cubemap depth textures [the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_depth_texture/) specifically says only `TEXTURE_2D` is supported.

> The error INVALID_OPERATION is generated in the following situations:
>
> - texImage2D is called with format and internalformat of DEPTH_COMPONENT
>     or DEPTH_STENCIL and target is not TEXTURE_2D,

You might have to switch to WebGL2. It works in both firefox and chrome

```js
function main() {
  const m4 = twgl.m4;
  const v3 = twgl.v3;
  const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl2");

  const width = 128;
  const height = 128;
  const colorTex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
    target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,
    minMag: gl.NEAREST,
    wrap: gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE,
    width: width,
    height: height,
  });

  // calls gl.createTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.texImage2D, gl.texParameteri
  const depthTex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
    target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,
    internalFormat: gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT24,
    format: gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT,
    type: gl.UNSIGNED_INT,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    wrap: gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE,
    minMax: gl.NEAREST,
  });

  const faces = [
    gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X,
    gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X,
    gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y,
    gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y,
    gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z,
    gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z,
  ];

  const fbs = faces.map(face => {
    const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, face, colorTex, 0);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, face, depthTex, 0);
    const status = gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (status !== gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
      console.log("can't use this framebuffer attachment combo");
    }
    return fb;
  });

  const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;
uniform mat4 u_worldInverseTranspose;
varying vec3 v_normal;
void main() {
gl_Position = u_worldViewProjection * position;
gl_Position.z = 0.5;
v_normal = (u_worldInverseTranspose * vec4(normal, 0)).xyz;
}
`;
  const fs = `
precision mediump float; 
uniform vec3 u_color;
uniform vec3 u_lightDir;
varying vec3 v_normal;
void main() {
float light = dot(u_lightDir, normalize(v_normal)) * .5 + .5;
gl_FragColor = vec4(u_color * light, 1);
}
`;

  const vs2 = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 u_matrix;
varying vec3 v_texcoord;
void main() {
gl_Position = u_matrix * position;
v_texcoord = position.xyz;
}
`;
  const fs2 = `
precision mediump float; 
uniform samplerCube u_cube;
varying vec3 v_texcoord;
void main() {
gl_FragColor = textureCube(u_cube, normalize(v_texcoord)) / vec4(2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
`;


  // compile shaders, links program, looks up locations
  const colorProgramInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
  // compile shaders, links program, looks up locations
  const cubeProgramInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs2, fs2]);
  // calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData
  const cubeBufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl);

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001; // seconds

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);

    gl.useProgram(colorProgramInfo.program);
    // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
    twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, colorProgramInfo, cubeBufferInfo);

    // draw a different color on each face
    faces.forEach((face, ndx) => {
      const c = ndx + 1;
      const color = [
        (c & 0x1) ? 1 : 0,
        (c & 0x2) ? 1 : 0,
        (c & 0x4) ? 1 : 0,
      ];
      gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fbs[ndx]);
      gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height);
      gl.clearColor(1 - color[0], 1 - color[1], 1 - color[2], 1);
      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

      const fov = Math.PI * 0.25;
      const aspect = width / height;
      const zNear = 0.001;
      const zFar = 100;
      const projection = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
      const world = m4.translation([0, 0, -3]);
      m4.rotateY(world, Math.PI * .1 * c * time, world);
      m4.rotateX(world, Math.PI * .15 * c * time, world);

      // calls gl.uniformXXX
      twgl.setUniforms(colorProgramInfo, {
        u_color: color,
        u_lightDir: v3.normalize([1, 5, 10]),
        u_worldViewProjection: m4.multiply(projection, world),
        u_worldInverseTranspose: m4.transpose(m4.inverse(world)),
      });

      // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
      twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, cubeBufferInfo);
    });

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.useProgram(cubeProgramInfo.program);
    // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
    twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, cubeProgramInfo, cubeBufferInfo);

    const fov = Math.PI * 0.25;
    const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
    const zNear = 0.001;
    const zFar = 10;
    const mat = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
    m4.translate(mat, [0, 0, -2], mat);
    m4.rotateY(mat, Math.PI * .25 * time, mat);
    m4.rotateX(mat, Math.PI * .25 * time, mat);

    twgl.setUniforms(cubeProgramInfo, {
      u_cube: colorTex,
      u_matrix: mat,
    });

    // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
    twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, cubeBufferInfo);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
main();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The extension is enabled and it is supported on the device I'm currently targeting, but good to know not all devices support it. 

The problem is that even with the extension enabled, it does not appear to work with cubemaps (on firefox anyway).

Comment: Well, according to the spec you don't pass `DEPTH_COMPONENT24` to `texImage2D`. In pass `DEPTH_COMPONENT` and the implementation chooses the resolution. You can check what resolution you got by calling `gl.getParameter(gl.DEPTH_BITS)`;

Comment: You are correct. That is what I did, I will edit the question to better explain that.

Comment: Will test your code once I get back in office to see if that gets the same error.

Comment: Hey gman, I've looked at the code and it seems there was a bit of a misunderstanding. What I want to do is use the DEPTH_COMPONENT format on a cubemap, not a TEXTURE_2D that is used in conjunction with a cubemap as render targets. Looking at the title of my question I understand where the confusion is coming from.

I've edited your code a little and made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h660x5my/). It looks like it works on chrome but not firefox :(

Comment: That's actually a bug in Chrome. [The spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_depth_texture/) specifically says only `TEXTURE_2D` is supported. You might have to switch to WebGL2. [It works in both firefox and chrome](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/7qztvu65/)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately webgl2 is a no-go because it's not broadly supported yet. It also seems to be incompatible with linear filtering.
It looks like I will have to save a float in 4 bytes (I'm using one of them as exponent) and implement linear filtering in the shader.

Comment: [Filed a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=718846)